# Looking for a mac app to design beautiful illustrations automatically and easily

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics

Check out for example:

[image: Illustration sample 1]

[image: Illustration sample 2]

I created these using Powerpoint on Mac, and then copying and pasting the image alone into a png and using that on a web page. What a pain and also the images look like Powerpoint images.

I bet there's a nice Mac app (or web site) that lets me create a wide variety of interesting illustrations that help me make a point. I have OmniGraffle which does some of this but I still have to be 'the illustrator'. Is there an app that works at a somewhat higher 'semantic' level?

Comment: If you know LaTeX maybe TikZ... But it's definitely not easy to use.

Comment: Are you familiar with PowerPoint capabilities ? You are using simple (as is) shapes without applying 3D rendering ect.... If you are an Artist there is unlimited possibilities to change your basic shapes in to art.

Answer (score 1):

[Apples Pages.](http://www.apple.com/uk/iwork/pages/)

I have used this only a little bit. But in most case it suits my basic needs. I have not tried to do anything really fancy. So cannot tell you if it is too limited for you

[image]